# How to plot DataFrames? in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataframe

I'm trying to plot a DataFrame, but I'm not getting the results I need. This is an example of what I'm trying to do and what I'm currently getting. (I'm new in Python)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_data = {1965:{'a':52, 'b':54, 'c':67, 'd':45}, 
      1966:{'a':34, 'b':34, 'c':35, 'd':76}, 
      1967:{'a':56, 'b':56, 'c':54, 'd':34}}  

df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
df.plot( style=[])
plt.show()
```

I'm getting the following graph, but what I need is: the years in the X axis and each line must be what is currently in X axis (a,b,c,d). Thanks for your help!!.

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe expand on what isn't working right? It isn't totally clear what you want the x-axis to look like.

Comment: Hi kikpatty... what I need is to have a plot that shows the years (1965, 1966,1967) in the X axis and each line will be a,b,c and d. For example, the blue line to be 'a', the green "b" and the red "c". Does it make sense?

Comment: It does. You may want to edit your question to clear that up for anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_data = {1965:{'a':52, 'b':54, 'c':67, 'd':45}, 
      1966:{'a':34, 'b':34, 'c':35, 'd':76}, 
      1967:{'a':56, 'b':56, 'c':54, 'd':34}}  

df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
df.T.plot( kind='bar') # or df.T.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Updates:

If this is what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
df.columns=[str(x) for x in df.columns] # convert year numerical values to str
df.T.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!... that I need is the same graph but as a "line plot", but when I do this, I can't see the years in the Y Axis.

Comment: Does changing `kind='bar'` to `kind='line'` solve this issue?

Comment: @PabloA.AstudilloEstévez, what d you mean "you cannot see years in the Y Axis". I'm plotting it as x-axis as mentioned in your question

Comment: @kirkpatt, when I do that I get "0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 +1.965e3" in the X Axis.

Comment: Sorry @MaThMaX, I meant X Axis.

Comment: @PabloA.AstudilloEstévez Alright, I'm sorry I can't help you further, but I am unable to install pandas right now. Anything else I say is just me taking shots in the dark, but you might want to try switching the years and the letters in `my_data`, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
ax = df.T.plot(linewidth=2.5)

plt.locator_params(nbins=len(df.columns))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%4d'))
```

[image]